The Peer Connection is closing just after starting
The connections is not being extablished
here is the log
Welcome to React Native DevTools
Debugger integration: Android Bridgeless (ReactHostImpl)
App.tsx:162 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 ctor +0ms
App.tsx:182 Created a new peer connection.
App.tsx:107 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 addTrack +4ms
App.tsx:110 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 createOffer +12ms
console.js:589 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 createOffer OK +7ms
App.tsx:111 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setLocalDescription +2ms
console.js:589 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setLocalDescription OK +21ms
App.tsx:84 Socket disconnect and cleanup on unmount.
App.tsx:192 Closing peer connection...
App.tsx:194 rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 close +15ms

App.tsx:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  mediaDevices,
  MediaStream,
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCIceCandidate,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const App = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [callerID, setCallerID] = useState('');
  const [currentCaller, setCurrentCaller] = useState('');
  const [callActive, setCallActive] = useState(false);
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);

  const peerConnection = useRef(null);
  const socket = useRef(null);
  let connectionClosed = false;

  const configuration = {
    iceServers: [
      { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
      {
        urls: 'turn:your-turn-server.com:3478', // Replace with your TURN server details
        username: 'your-username',
        credential: 'your-password',
      },
    ],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io('http://192.168.0.125:8000'); // Replace with your server IP

    socket.current.on('connected', (data) => {
      if (data.success) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
        Alert.alert('Login Successful', `Welcome ${data.username}`);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Error', data.message);
      }
    });

    socket.current.on('webrtc_signal', async (data) => {
      if (data.signal.type === 'offer') {
        handleIncomingOffer(data);
      } else if (data.signal.type === 'answer') {
        if (peerConnection.current) {
          peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(
            new RTCSessionDescription(data.signal.sdp)
          );
        }
      } else if (data.signal.type === 'candidate') {
        if (peerConnection.current) {
          peerConnection.current.addIceCandidate(
            new RTCIceCandidate(data.signal.candidate)
          );
        }
      }
    });

    socket.current.on('call_ended', () => {
      if (!callActive) {
        console.log('Ignoring call_ended event since no active call.');
        return;
      }
      Alert.alert('Call Ended', `The call with ${currentCaller} has ended.`);
      endCall();
    });

    return () => {
      console.log('Socket disconnect and cleanup on unmount.');
      socket.current.disconnect();
      closeConnection();
    };
  }, [currentCaller]);

  const userLogin = () => {
    if (!username) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Username cannot be empty!');
      return;
    }
    socket.current.emit('login', { name: username });
  };

  const callUser = async () => {
    if (!callerID) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Enter a username to call.');
      return;
    }

    createPeerConnection();

    localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    const offer = await peerConnection.current.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(offer);

    socket.current.emit('webrtc_signal', {
      target: callerID,
      signal: { type: 'offer', sdp: peerConnection.current.localDescription },
    });

    setCallActive(true);
    setCurrentCaller(callerID);
  };

  const handleIncomingOffer = async (data) => {
    createPeerConnection();

    await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(
      new RTCSessionDescription(data.signal.sdp)
    );

    localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    const answer = await peerConnection.current.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(answer);

    socket.current.emit('webrtc_signal', {
      target: data.sender,
      signal: { type: 'answer', sdp: peerConnection.current.localDescription },
    });

    setCallActive(true);
    setCurrentCaller(data.sender);
  };

  const endCall = () => {
    console.log('Ending call...');
    if (currentCaller) {
      socket.current.emit('call_ended', { target: currentCaller });
    }
    setCallActive(false);
    setCurrentCaller('');
    closeConnection();
  };

  const createPeerConnection = () => {
    connectionClosed = false; // Reset the flag
    if (peerConnection.current) {
      console.log('Peer connection already exists.');
      return;
    }

    peerConnection.current = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    peerConnection.current.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        socket.current.emit('webrtc_signal', {
          target: currentCaller,
          signal: { type: 'candidate', candidate: event.candidate },
        });
      }
    };

    peerConnection.current.ontrack = (event) => {
      const stream = new MediaStream(event.streams[0].getTracks());
      setRemoteStream(stream);

      const audio = new Audio();
      audio.srcObject = stream;
      audio.play();
    };

    console.log('Created a new peer connection.');
  };

  const closeConnection = () => {
    if (connectionClosed) {
      console.log('closeConnection already called, skipping.');
      return;
    }
    connectionClosed = true;

    console.log('Closing peer connection...');
    if (peerConnection.current) {
      peerConnection.current.close();
      peerConnection.current = null;
    }

    if (remoteStream) {
      remoteStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      setRemoteStream(null);
    }
    if (localStream) {
      localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      setLocalStream(null);
    }
  };

  const startMedia = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      setLocalStream(stream);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error accessing media devices:', err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO);
    startMedia();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!loggedIn && (
        <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Enter your username"
            value={username}
            onChangeText={setUsername}
          />
          <Button title="Login" onPress={userLogin} />
        </View>
      )}

      {loggedIn && !callActive && (
        <View style={styles.callerContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Enter username to call"
            value={callerID}
            onChangeText={setCallerID}
          />
          <Button title="Call" onPress={callUser} />
        </View>
      )}

      {callActive && (
        <View style={styles.callStatusContainer}>
          <Text>In a call with {currentCaller}</Text>
          <Button title="End Call" onPress={endCall} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  loginContainer: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  callerContainer: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  callStatusContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    padding: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
    borderRadius: 4,
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default App;

just for reference here is backend
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import cors from "cors";
import { Socket } from "socket.io";
/**
 * Initialize the socket.io connection for voice calling
 * @param {Server} io - The Socket.IO server instance
 */
const initializeSocketIO = (io) => {
  const activeUsers = {};

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected");

    socket.on("login", (data) => {
      const { name: username } = data;
      if (activeUsers[username]) {
        socket.emit("connected", {
          success: false,
          message: "Username already in use",
        });
      } else {
        socket.username = username;
        activeUsers[username] = socket;

        socket.emit("connected", {
          success: true,
          username,
          userlist: Object.keys(activeUsers),
        });
        console.log(`User logged in: ${username}`);
      }
    });

    socket.on("webrtc_signal", (data) => {
      const targetSocket = activeUsers[data.target];
      if (targetSocket) {
        console.log(`Forwarding signal from ${socket.username} to ${data.target}`);
        targetSocket.emit("webrtc_signal", {
          sender: socket.username,
          signal: data.signal,
        });
      } else {
        socket.emit("webrtc_error", {
          message: `User ${data.target} is not available`,
        });
      }
    });

    socket.on("call_user", (data) => {
      const targetSocket = activeUsers[data.target];
      if (targetSocket) {
        console.log(`User ${socket.username} is calling ${data.target}`);
        targetSocket.emit("call_user", { caller: socket.username });
      } else {
        socket.emit("call_response", { response: "offline" });
      }
    });

    socket.on("call_response", (data) => {
      const callerSocket = activeUsers[data.caller];
      if (callerSocket) {
        console.log(
          `Call response from ${socket.username} to ${data.caller}: ${data.response}`
        );
        callerSocket.emit("call_response", {
          response: data.response,
          responder: socket.username,
        });
      }
    });

    socket.on("call_ended", (data) => {
      const targetSocket = activeUsers[data.target];
      if (targetSocket) {
        console.log(`Call ended between ${socket.username} and ${data.target}`);
        targetSocket.emit("call_ended", { sender: socket.username });
      }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(`User disconnected: ${socket.username}`);
      if (socket.username) {
        delete activeUsers[socket.username];
      }
    });
  });
};

export { initializeSocketIO };

and also the app is first connected to backend cause the
User connected

is being logged in server
I am trying to create a basic calling app with node server but the app is working fine when using a basic html for frontend, but when I try to use react-native the connection is not being established
